# Show scrollbars on top of position:absolute header

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've got a wrapper with content that is larger than it in both directions. Try scrolling in either direction on the table here: https://we-flow.github.io/react-sticky-table/

The vertical scrollbar is visible as I would like it to be with the exception of it being hidden behind the table header until you scroll down a bit.

The horizontal scrollbar is only visible once you scroll all the way to the bottom, and then it behaves like the vertical scrollbar (hiding behind the sticky column).

It's clear why this is happening: Both the sticky header and column are `position: absolute` and of a higher `z-index` than the main content `div` that overflows its parent.

**What I would like is for both scrollbars to be visible at all times and above the sticky headers.** My guess is this isn't possible with CSS, but maybe there is a magical solution with JS and a library like this: https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars

The basic structure of the table is this:

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2;">Header</div>

  <div style="position: relative; overflow-y: auto; width: 100%;">
    <div style="position:absolute; z-index: 1;">Column</div>

    <div style="overflow-x: auto; height: 100%;">
       <div>Content that overflows in both directions</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps this structure would be simpler and get you what you want. Remove a few layers of nesting and use margins.

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">

  <div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2;">Header</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; z-index: 1;">Column</div>

    <div style="margin: header-size 0px 0px cell-size;" height: 100%;">
       <div>Content that overflows in both directions</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you absolutely *have* to stick with the structure you have, then, yes, you could use javascript to change the width of the header when the content is scrollable to fix the vertical scroll bar being obscured, but there's nothing you can do about the horizontal scroll bar in your current format, because the container that's scrolling in the `y` direction isn't the same as the one that's scrolling in the `x` direction.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the answer, but I'm not having any luck getting this to work on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z2dd26zq/

Comment: Oh, yes, I see now. Yes, it's probably not possible with css to do what you want without the sticky column/header covering the scrollbar.

Comment: Your best bet would be a javascript listener on the scroll event of that container and continue to update the position of your sticky elements to be equal to scroll top or scroll left. 

And, as far as performance concerns, I would make sure you debounce the scroll listener by at least 100ms, and use transform as opposed to position absolute to move the sticky elements.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z2dd26zq/