# how to contain fixed bar in relative div and show scrollbar perfectly

Tags: html, css

I want to contain fixed bar in relative div. But scrollbar is vanished on fixed bar area. 
I want to know how to show perfect scrollbar without vanished area.

code below.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="scrolling-contents">
        <div class="fixed-wrapper">
          <div class="fixed-bar">
            fixed bar
          </div>
        </div>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
        aaaaaaa<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
    .wrapper {
        top: 20px;
    }
    .scrolling-contents {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;

        background-color: #CCC;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .fixed-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .fixed-bar {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
    }
```

I want to get scrollbar width according to container div.

Screenshot below:

[image: Screen shot]

You can check vanished scrollbar because of fixed bar area.

Comment: Why not just reduce the the `width` of `.fixed-bar` to `calc(100% - 10px)`?

Comment: @Nimsrules Fixed bar has not 100% width when div has not scrollbar

Comment: You've explicitly declared `width: 100%;` to `.fixed-bar` in your CSS, haven't you?

Comment: @Nimsrules I want to hold 100% width of fixed bar when div has scrollbar or none scrollbar with not vanished scrollbar.

Comment: @Nimsrules yes, I declared 100% width of fixed bar in container div.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want the scrollbar over the absolutely positioned element. Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082396/show-scrollbars-on-top-of-positionabsolute-header

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to add absolute position to the fixed bar? By looking to what you want to achieve, this seems to be enough:

```css
.wrapper {
            position: relative;
            top: 20px;
        }
        .scrolling-contents {
            width: 100%;
            height: 250px;
    
            background-color: #CCC;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .fixed-wrapper {
           /* Removed position:absolute */
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .fixed-bar {
           /* Removed position:absolute */
            background-color: red;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="fixed-wrapper">
            <div class="fixed-bar">
              fixed bar
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="scrolling-contents">
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
            aaaaaaa<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not contained wrapper div. For example, when I set fixed bar on middle inside wrapper div using 'top: 5rem;', It's not set on middle in wrapper div.